# Google Sheets formula to extract dates

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have this data in google sheets:

[image]

Looking to only get a  date from the cell, example 1.4.2020

I tried something like below but doesn't work.
Any idea what replacement to do?

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(B51,"[^[:digit:][:punct:]]", ""))
```

Comment: There are lots of incorrect words in your post!

Answer (score 1):

Yes try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B51,"\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}")
```

Or if not other digits exists:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B51,"\d.*\d")
```

Comment: @Ineedhelp, you should comment to these answers and mark one to close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

paste in C51:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B51:B54, "\d+\.\d+\.\d+")))
```