# How to Extract Date from String in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet that contains 1000+ rows.

In Column B, I have a text string which contains a date.

Example:

```
Written by <!-- -->John Doe<!-- --> on <!-- -->Wed Nov 17 2021<!-- -->.
```

How can I extract **Nov 17 2021** from this string?

If it helps: The date always appears between the 2nd to last ">" and the last "<".

I've already checked [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262179/extracting-date-from-text-in-google-sheets) and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006200/google-sheets-formula-to-extract-dates), but neither seem to apply to my situation because the date in my string is formatted differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=regexextract(A1,"\w{3} \d{2} \d{4}")*1
```

then define the format you wish
[image]

for a complete column (as B)

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(B1:B,"\w{3} \d{2} \d{4}")*1))
```